# How to calculate Naive Bayes Posterior Probability in Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, probability

I have trained a model using the Classification Learner app, and have successfully tested the model using test data. 
Now, I would like to achieve a certainty/confidence/probability to indicate how 'sure' the program is that the classification is correct. 
For example, I would like something like "Class - 1, Certainty - 89%".

I have done background reading and found the Naive Bayes Posterior Probability, but am unsure how to implement this into my code.

```
VarNames = arrayfun(@(N) sprintf('VarNames%d', N), 1:200, 'Uniform', 0):
testData = array2table(data, 'VariablesNames', VarNames);
result = trainedModel.predictFcn(testData);
```

The code correctly outputs the classifications, for example result = 3 3 2 1 3 where 1, 2 and 3 are the classes. However, I am unsure what code to use to also display the probability/certainty of each classification

Example:
Class - 1, Probability - 89%

Comment: I am not sure to understand your issue... Does your code throw an error?

Comment: Hi Ary,
No, i do not get an error. The code correctly outputs the classifications, for example
result = 
3
3
2
1
3

where 1, 2 and 3 are the classes.

However, I am unsure what code to use to also display the probability/certainty of each classification.

Comment: Ok, you can have a look here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationensemble.predict.html, which can give you the scores. Just make sure that the trainedModel.PredictorNames and testData have the same variables names and contain the same data types.

Comment: @matlab_user98: Welcome to SO. It's unclear what question you are trying to ask. Please refer to [the guide page on minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide that edits that will show what is expected of your code and what you have done to debug. Also be sure to limit to programming questions. Statistics has a separate stackexchange site. See the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.